# How to count from two table using JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

Im an newbie and stuck with this case
i have two tables

Category
- CatId
- CatName

Product
- ProductId
- CatId
- ProductName

i want to count how many product in category when showing category with counting product  and im using this query

```
SELECT * , COUNT(Product.ProductId) AS NumberProducts FROM Category
JOIN Product
ON Category.CatId = Product.CatId
GROUP BY Product.CatId
```

this query just working if i have product exists with catid in table Product, if not my category wont show on category list, category will disappear.

please help. thanks in advance

Comment: determine what columns (not *) you want to truly do the group by

Comment: select s.col1,s.col2,t.colA,count(t.colB) from table1 s join table2 t on (something) group by s.col1,s.col2,t.colA

Comment: Google and learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Comment: @Drew : im trying your suggest but its not working. maybe im using incorrect syntax :(

Comment: would like to help if you showed the schema for both tables with `show create table xxx` for each, plus what you really want to show (not select *)

Comment: @Drew : simply i want to print out all my category in table category with counted product with that CatId in Product table. if Product dont have existing product with that catid , category will display as 0 product.
Example:
- Cat 1: 1 products
- cat 2: 0 products ( dont have any product with this catid in product table )

Comment: then why in the world are you doing `select *`. Show the columns you care about

Comment: and if it is that simple, look what @TabAlleman said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select * is the problem - you were looking for the list of categories and product count.

You will get what you are asking. (c and p are aliases to make SQL more readable)

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(p.ProductId) AS NumberProducts FROM Category as c
LEFT JOIN Product as p
ON c.CatId = p.CatId
GROUP BY c.CatId
```

Produces

```
CatId   CategoryName    NumberProducts
1       T-Shirts        2
2       Sneakers        0
3       Boots           0
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Glad to be helpful @HienPham

Comment: Thanks again jpaljasma

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * , COUNT(Product.ProductId) AS NumberProducts FROM Category
LEFT JOIN Product
ON Category.CatId = Product.CatId
GROUP BY Product.CatId
```

Left Join should do the trick

Comment: im already using LEFT JOIN but category not showing up with 0 product. Im try using LEFT OUTER JOIN result will return first empty category and other empty not showing up

Comment: Change the GROUP BY to Category.CatId instead of Product.CatId.  Then it won't combine all the empty categories.

Comment: @Simon : category with none product ( 0 ) still not showing up :(